# Adding a user to Cognito User Pool in iOS

Tags: swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

The case is very simple, I want to add to my cognito user pool a new user with a given information, this is what I got so far:

```
        let emailValue = email.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let passwordValue = password.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let firstNameValue = firstName.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        let lastNameValue = lastName.text!.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        var attributes = [AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType]()
        let firstName = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
        firstName?.name = "first_name"
        firstName?.value = firstNameValue
        attributes.append(firstName!)
        let lastName = AWSCognitoIdentityUserAttributeType()
        lastName?.name = "last_name"
        lastName?.value = lastNameValue
        attributes.append(lastName!)
        self.pool?.signUp(emailValue, password: passwordValue, userAttributes: attributes, validationData: nil)
```

this is where I define my pool (using constants):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.pool = AWSCognitoIdentityUserPool.init(forKey: AWSCognitoUserPoolsSignInProviderKey)
}
```

There are no errors but after I execute the function (with a press) nothing happens.
What am I doing wrong?